# Why won't a Boolean cast narrow type in short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to narrow an optional argument in short-circuit evaluation.

Here's a Typescript playground with the below code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgA5zWmAIwBsBPAVTABMVgYwUqB+ALkQwCd6BzASkQDeAWABQiRAHoJiAO4ALFEghwQxKogAGufETKUadBlQ2IEyBYi7c5URHICG1djBqJCKROAP1GTUeI4UKBAOJAAhODhiFEccPAISCmpaHyp+ADJ0xG0EvWTDRgA6aLBuKDkAblEAXyA

```
function test(possiblyUndefined?: string) {
  // when could `possiblyUndefined` on the right hand side be undefined?
  return Boolean(possiblyUndefined) && possiblyUndefined.length;
}
```

This errors out with: `'possiblyUndefined' is possibly 'undefined'.`

...But that can't be right. The left-hand side of the statement can only ever succeed when `possiblyUndefined` is *not* undefined, right?

Comment: As far as TS is concerned, `Boolean` returns a `boolean`, which has no information about what `possiblyUndefined` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `Boolean` function will happily accept `undefined`, and TypeScript doesn't have it defined as a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that guarantees its input isn't `undefined` (probably because that's not its purpose, even though it's true that `Boolean` will return `false` for `undefined`). If you look at the current definition of it, it's this (relevant portion highlighted):

```typescript
interface BooleanConstructor {
    new(value?: any): Boolean;
    <T>(value?: T): boolean;             // <====
    readonly prototype: Boolean;
}

declare var Boolean: BooleanConstructor;
```

That's just a function that returns `boolean`, not a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).¹

If you want to handle `undefined`, you can do so explicitly. I'd also use `> 0` so your function always returns `boolean`, not `false | number` (though that's up to you, of course):

```
return typeof possiblyUndefined !== "undefined" && possiblyUndefined.length > 0;
// or
return possiblyUndefined !== undefined && possiblyUndefined.length > 0;
```

Although these days I think I'd probably go for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`):

```
return possiblyUndefined?.length ?? 0 > 0;
```

[Playground link for the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgA5zWmAIwBsBPAVTABMVgYwUqB+ALkQwCd6BzASkQDeAWABQicYg4ooIDkiilsKOMES58RMpRp0GVRAEIAvEcQAicDvqMziAGR21eAiQrVa1qgDpiKMNygAC0QAPkQABgBuUQBfUVFQSFgEZHQoACYcZ003Kz1Wdiguf35hMQkpGTknDVdtDz1DE0RLBsZ7R3UXLXddRh8-AOCwqNj4kUToeHk0gGYs2p68xgLOHlLRCUlpWSQunPq+5gH-IMQmJgjQiOiROJEgA)

---

¹ It's interesting to see from [the link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16655) in Leland's own answer that there's at least talk of *making* it a predicate function. But it isn't one as of this writing. It's just a conversion function.

Comment: "that's not its purpose" seems like the thesis of your answer. But I'm struggling to understand, then, why `!!possiblyUndefined` successfully narrows type? To me this simply appears like something TS just hasn't implemented yet.

Comment: @Leland - Because `!` does type conversion at a language level. `!undefined` is the value `true`, and `!true` is `false`, and TypeScript knows that. But the purpose of `Boolean` is to give `true` or `false` for a given input, and as I said, it's not (currently) defined as a type predicate function in TypeScript's types for it. (It's a conversion function.) Your link shows that there has been discussion of possibly making it one at some point, but it isn't one right now.

Comment: Like TJ said, `Boolean` does not come with a type predicate, which is necessary if you want a function to somehow return type information about something. You can see that if you add a type predicate to `BooleanConstructor` (the type of `Boolean`), it works: https://tsplay.dev/wXOgJW

Comment: (I should also say the thesis of my answer is that `Boolean` isn't typed as a predicate function. I suggested one reason that might be [that's not its purpose], but that's not my thesis, that's just a speculation.)

Comment: TIL that you can change global interfaces. Thanks!

Comment: @Leland - You **can**, but changing the ones TypeScript defines for the JavaScript standard library is probably not a good idea. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. This is a missing feature in Typescript.

> Boolean() cannot be used to perform a null check

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16655

Comment: `!!x` can't be used either, I wish it could but that would be a nightmare to implement.

Comment: Sorry, I believe you are wrong https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgA5zWmAIwBsBPAVTABMVgYwUqB+ALkQwCd6BzASkQDeAWABQiRAHoJiAO4ALFEghwQxKogAGufETKUadBlQ2IEyBYi7c5URHICG1djBqJCKROAP1GTUeI4UKBAOJABCMO0CEgpqWh91ADJExCjdWO8jADpiRW4oOQBuUQBfIA

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, I was looking at when the return type is annotated to be `boolean`: https://tsplay.dev/m3xKkW lol

Comment: That's an unrelated error. It's clear that `!!` successfully narrows type in that short circuit: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEziARgGwKYCECGYA5gOpwBOA1gM4AUADnNdTFgJ4CqYy2wMY2ZAH4AXImpRy-IgEox6OHByFEAbwCwAKESJy2KCHJIAhMcbNWmTt179BiAGQPE5luy48+A5ADocxKAALRAA+RAAGAG4tAF8tLVBIWAREKGwJACYGJjcrD1tvUXFJaTlEBSVsFQ1tXX1DJFxFZTBsi3cbL0EZR2dXS2tPO19-IiDQiOjNGKA